# javascript/jquery - table.rows[i] is undefined

Tags: javascript

what is wrong in with my script. it throws error message table.rows[i] is undefined. iam new to jquery thanks in advance :)

update:
sorry for the lack of info, 
error occurs in this line **"table.rows[i].cells[3].onclick"**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var index, table = document.getElementById('resultset');

    for (var i = 1; i < table.rows.length; i++) {
        table.rows[i].cells[3].onclick = function () {
            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: 'Getdetail',
                datatype: "json",
                data: {
                    mydata: table.rows[i].cells[0]

                },
                success: function (data) {
                    alert(data);
                }

            });
        };

    }
});
```

Comment: You really should provide a [mcve] so that we can reproduce the problem, and when quoting an error message about a variable that appears multiple times in the code: Say which instance the error is about!

Comment: javascript array start with index 0 try with for (var i = 0; i < table.rows.length; i++) i think that in the last iteration loop overflow

Comment: @JFouad — It is not unusual to want to skip the header row of a table, and you're wrong about the last iteration overflowing.

Comment: sorry for the lack of info, i added the exact location of the error. i tried the said duplicate issue but its different.

Comment: I think you have to change your method in accessing specific cell of your table.

Comment: I think you have to change your method in accessing specific cell of your table. Use `    table.getElementsByTagName("tr") instead of table.rows[i], as well as use getElementsByTagName("td") on every <tr> element instead of rows[i].cells[0]